# Cross-checking dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a Pandas issue.

Currently in df1:

| start | Stop |
| --- | --- |
| NYPenn | WUnion |
| GCTerm | 30thSt |
| TUStat | LAUnio |
| JaStat | MillSt |
| ChiUnS | MonCen |
| OGTran | SouthS |

Currently in df2 (Prime):

| Train_Code | City |
| --- | --- |
| NYPenn | New York City |
| WUnion | D.C. |
| GCTerm | New York City |
| 30thSt | Philadelphia |
| TUStat | Toronto |
| LAUnio | Los Angeles |
| MonCen | Montreal |
| OGTran | Chicago |
| SouthS | Boston |

I want to use the train codes to determine which start/stop in df1 contain prime stations. I would need to run each element in both columns in df1 against df2 (Train_Code) to output the results indicating which station was a prime (or if both stations are prime) into another dataframe (df3).

df3 should end up being:

| start | Stop | Results | City | Results | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NYPenn | WUnion | Yes | New York City | Yes | D.C. |
| GCTerm | 30thSt |  |  |  |  |
| TUStat | LAUnio |  |  |  |  |
| JaStat | MillSt | NO | NaN | NO | NaN |
| ChiUnS | MonCen | NO | NaN | Yes | Montreal |
| OGTran | SouthS |  |  |  |  |

**Note: I didn't fill in df3 all the way but I gave examples of how it should be filled.

[If I added another column indicating there was a layover station, the code should work run against the layover column as well.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you close:

```
df1s = df1.stack().rename('Train_Code').to_frame()
df1s.loc[:,'City'] = df1s['Train_Code'].map(df2.set_index('Train_Code')['City'])
df1s['Results'] = np.where(df1s['City'].notna(), 'Yes', 'NO')
df1s.unstack()
```

Output:

```
      Train_Code                   City               Results     
       start    Stop          start          Stop   start Stop
0     NYPenn  WUnion  New York City          D.C.     Yes  Yes
1     GCTerm  30thSt  New York City  Philadelphia     Yes  Yes
2     TUStat  LAUnio        Toronto   Los Angeles     Yes  Yes
3     JaStat  MillSt            NaN           NaN      NO   NO
4     ChiUnS  MonCen            NaN      Montreal      NO  Yes
5     OGTran  SouthS        Chicago        Boston     Yes  Yes
```

Comment: Is there a For loop that will work for this situation ? I am having issues with the code provided.